# Ubuntu 14.04 and latest supported AMD Catalyst 14.6 Beta driver (fglrx) intermittently hangs system - unreliable stability

Tags: radeon, fglrx, catalyst, beta, ubuntu-drivers

My system reliability has been compromised since upgrading to Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 on a AMD64 system with a Radeon R9 290X card and installing the official AMD Catalyst 14.6 Beta driver. It now hangs the latest desktop system intermittently (which it did NOT do before setting up the card by installing the latest official beta Catalyst drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 - and also this behaviour was not observed with the previous Ubuntu 12.04.5 release installed with the previous up-to-date Catalyst Beta driver supported for Ubuntu 12.04.5). Sometimes the desktop system locks up (hard hangs) and requires a power-cycle, yet other times the system restarts and boots up as normal presenting GDM for GNOME desktop login.

Is this a driver issue and/or X11 issue? What should I do in order to solicit more diagnostic information and what tests are recommended for potential troubleshooting of the driver?

Please review my config/logs...

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT [Radeon R9 290X]


$ sudo grep fglrx /var/log/syslog       
Oct 24 15:00:21 linexus kernel: [   11.761650] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7503 MBytes.
Oct 24 15:00:21 linexus kernel: [   11.761865] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 67b0 count: 1
Oct 24 15:00:21 linexus kernel: [   11.762565] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xd000, size: 0x100
Oct 24 15:00:21 linexus kernel: [   11.762799] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
Oct 24 15:00:21 linexus kernel: [   11.762815] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 14.20.7 [May 29 2014] with 1 minors
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.134971] fglrx_pci 0000:02:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.135698] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1808
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.135788] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1809
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.135854] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1810
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.135975] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 44 Enabled
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.166286] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.166288] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f738000, size:4000 
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.166290] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f73c000, size:4c4000 
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.166291] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fc00000, size:100000 
Oct 24 15:00:24 linexus kernel: [   14.166292] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:ffff4000, size:c000



$ sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    13.905] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    13.905] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    13.905] Current Operating System: Linux linexus 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    13.905] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/ROOT/ubuntu-1@/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu-1 ro boot=zfs
[    13.905] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[    13.905] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    13.905] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    13.905]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    13.905] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    13.905] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct 24 16:29:52 2014
[    13.905] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    13.905] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    13.908] (==) ServerLayout "aticonfig Layout"
[    13.908] (**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
[    13.908] (**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
[    13.908] (**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
[    13.908] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    13.908] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    13.908] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
...
[    13.909] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    13.909] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    13.909] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fb8bfbb7d40
[    13.909] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    13.909]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    13.909]     X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    13.909]     X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    13.909]     X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    13.910] (--) PCI:*(0:1:5:0) 1002:9616:1043:8388 rev 0, Mem @ 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xfe9f0000/65536, 0xfe800000/1048576, I/O @ 0x0000c000/256
[    13.910] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 1002:67b0:1002:0b00 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xcf800000/8388608, 0xfeac0000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    13.910] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    13.911] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    13.911] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    13.911] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    13.911] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    13.911] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    13.918] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[    13.918]     compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[    13.918] Loading extension GLX
[    13.918] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    13.918] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    14.020] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    14.020]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[    14.021]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    14.022] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    14.022] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    14.022] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    14.025] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    14.025]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[    14.025] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:14.20.7
[    14.025] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-14.20                    
[    14.025] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: May 29 2014 10:25:55
[    14.025] (++) using VT number 7

[    14.042] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    14.063] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    14.066] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.066] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.066] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:2:0:0
[    14.066] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    14.066] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    14.356] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 9
[    14.356] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
[    14.379] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:5:0) found
[    14.379] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x67B0) found
...
[    14.381] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7fb8c114e4c0
[    14.381] (II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_xs115_atiddxPreInit] === begin
[    14.381] (**) fglrx(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    14.381] (II) fglrx(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    14.381] (==) fglrx(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    14.381] (**) fglrx(0): Option "DPMS" "true"
[    14.381] (==) fglrx(0): RGB weight 888
[    14.381] (II) fglrx(0): Using 8 bits per RGB 
[    14.382] (==) fglrx(0): Buffer Tiling is ON
[    14.382] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    14.382] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    14.382] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    14.382] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    14.382]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.20.7
[    14.384] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.384] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.384] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:2:0:0
[    14.384] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    14.384] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 11, (OK)
[    14.384] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 11
[    14.384] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
[    14.384] (**) fglrx(0): NoAccel = NO
[    14.384] (**) fglrx(0): AMD 2D Acceleration Architecture enabled
[    14.384] (--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon R9 200 Series" (Chipset = 0x67b0)
[    14.384] (--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x1002, PciSubDevice = 0x0b00)
[    14.384] (==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: original AMD graphics adapter
[    14.384] (--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xd0000000
[    14.384] (--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xfeac0000
[    14.384] (--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x0000d000
[    14.384] (==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): AC Adapter is used
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): AMD Video BIOS revision 9 or later detected
[    14.387] (--) fglrx(0): Video RAM: 4194304 kByte, Type: GDDR5
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): PCIE card detected
[    14.387] (--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): board/chipset is supported by this driver (original AMD board)
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0xf400000000, MCFBSize = 0x100000000)
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 support is enabled!
[    14.387] (II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 rotation support is enabled!
[    14.387] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    14.387] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    14.388] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    14.391] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    14.391]     compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.391]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    14.391] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Management option: EDID Management is enabled
[    14.391] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    14.391] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    14.391] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 using monitor section aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP3 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP4 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP5 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP6 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP7 has no monitor section
[    14.480] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    14.480] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    14.480] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Connected Display0: DFP7
[    14.480] (II) fglrx(0): Display0 EDID data ---------------------------
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a08d  Serial#: 826493516
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Year: 2013  Week: 14
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 60  vert.: 34
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.315 greenY: 0.623
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.063   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Supported established timings:
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Supported standard timings:
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): #2: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  598 x 336 mm
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Serial No: P7D0G3411CJL
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Monitor name: DELL S2740L
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0): EDID (in hex):
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0):     00ffffffffffff0010ac8da04c4a4331
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0):     0e170103803c2278eaeed5a356509f26
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0):     105054a54b00714f8180d1c001010101
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0):     010101010101023a801871382d40582c
[    14.481] (II) fglrx(0):     450056502100001e000000ff00503744
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0):     304733343131434a4c0a000000fc0044
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0):     454c4c2053323734304c0a20000000fd
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0):     00384c1e5311000a20202020202000b4
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): End of Display0 EDID data --------------------
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Dynamic Surface Resizing Enabled
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP1
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP2
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP3
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP4
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP5
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP6
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP7
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a08d  Serial#: 826493516
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Year: 2013  Week: 14
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 60  vert.: 34
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    14.482] (II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.315 greenY: 0.623
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.063   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Supported established timings:
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Supported standard timings:
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): #2: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  598 x 336 mm
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Serial No: P7D0G3411CJL
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Monitor name: DELL S2740L
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): EDID (in hex):
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     00ffffffffffff0010ac8da04c4a4331
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     0e170103803c2278eaeed5a356509f26
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     105054a54b00714f8180d1c001010101
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     010101010101023a801871382d40582c
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     450056502100001e000000ff00503744
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     304733343131434a4c0a000000fc0044
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     454c4c2053323734304c0a20000000fd
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0):     00384c1e5311000a20202020202000b4
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Printing probed modes for output DFP7
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  148.50  1680 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  148.50  1400 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.483] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  148.50  1600 2008 2052 2200  900 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x60.0  148.50  1440 2008 2052 2200  900 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x960"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  960 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  960 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0  148.50  1152 2008 2052 2200  864 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  768 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  768 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  720 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  720 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP3 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP4 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP5 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP6 disconnected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP7 connected
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP7 using initial mode 1920x1080
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Eyefinity capable adapter detected.
[    14.484] (II) fglrx(0): Adapter AMD Radeon R9 200 Series has 6 configurable heads and 1 displays connected.
[    14.484] (==) fglrx(0):  PseudoColor visuals disabled
[    14.485] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    14.485] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    14.485] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    14.485] (==) fglrx(0): NoDRI = NO
[    14.485] (==) fglrx(0): Capabilities: 0x00000000
[    14.485] (==) fglrx(0): CapabilitiesEx: 0x00000000
[    14.485] (==) fglrx(0): OpenGL ClientDriverName: "fglrx_dri.so"
[    14.485] (==) fglrx(0): UseFastTLS=0
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): Shadow Primary option: ShadowPrimary is enabled
[    14.485] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    14.485] Loading extension ATIFGLRXDRI
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): doing swlDriScreenInit
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit for fglrx driver
[    14.485] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.485] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.485] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.485] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:2:0:0
[    14.485] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    14.485] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 12, (OK)
[    14.485] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 12
[    14.485] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] DRM interface version 1.0
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] created "fglrx" driver at busid "PCI:2:0:0"
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 8192 byte SAREA at 0x2000
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] mapped SAREA 0x2000 to 0x7fb8bf77b000
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] framebuffer handle = 0x3000
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 1 reserved context for kernel
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit done
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Version Information:
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0):     Name: fglrx
[    14.485] (II) fglrx(0):     Version: 14.20.7
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Date: May 29 2014
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Desc: AMD FireGL DRM kernel module
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module version matches driver.
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Build Time Information:
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel UTS_RELEASE:        3.13.0-37-generic
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel MODVERSIONS:        yes
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel __SMP__:            yes
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel PAGE_SIZE:          0x1000
[    14.486] (II) fglrx(0): [uki] register handle = 0x00004000
[    14.490] (II) fglrx(0): DRI initialization successfull
[    14.490] (II) fglrx(0): FBADPhys: 0xf400000000 FBMappedSize: 0x010e0000
[    14.491] (==) fglrx(0): Backing store enabled
[    14.491] Loading extension FGLRXEXTENSION
[    14.491] (**) fglrx(0): DPMS enabled
[    14.491] (II) fglrx(0): Initialized in-driver Xinerama extension
[    14.491] (**) fglrx(0): Textured Video is enabled.
[    14.491] (II) LoadModule: "glesx"
[    14.491] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/glesx.so
[    14.528] (II) Module glesx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    14.528]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.528] Loading extension GLESX
[    14.528] (II) fglrx(0): GLESX enableFlags = 8784
[    14.529] (II) fglrx(0): GLESX is enabled
[    14.529] (II) LoadModule: "amdxmm"
[    14.529] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/amdxmm.so
[    14.532] (II) Module amdxmm: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    14.532]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 2.0.0
[    14.535] Loading extension AMDXVOPL
[    14.535] Loading extension AMDXVBA
[    14.535] (II) fglrx(0): Enable composite support successfully
[    14.536] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "VendorName" is not used
[    14.536] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "ModelName" is not used
[    14.536] (II) fglrx(0): X context handle = 0x1
[    14.536] (II) fglrx(0): [DRI] installation complete
[    14.536] (==) fglrx(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    14.537] (==) fglrx(0): Using HW cursor of display infrastructure!
[    14.538] (II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    14.578] (--) RandR disabled
[    14.582] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    14.583] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.583] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.583] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:2:0:0
[    14.583] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    14.583] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 13, (OK)
[    14.583] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 13
[    14.583] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
[    14.584] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    14.584] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    14.584] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    14.715] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.715] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.715] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 14, (OK)
[    14.715] ukiGetBusid returned 'PCI:2:0:0'
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card2
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    14.715] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
...
```